# Was Jonah Wizard based on any specific celebrity?

Tags: inspiration, the-39-clues

In the *The 39 Clues* series, Jonah Wizard is the Cahill's famous face - he's a star hip-hop musician, and he gets mobbed everywhere. He's a celebrity - he flies private planes, has tons of money, etc. He talks like a 'gangsta'. Here's an example:

> "Wassup, Pierce Landing? *The Wiz is in the house!*"
>   <sub>-*The 39 Clues; Unstoppable: Flashpoint*, chapter 26</sub>

...

> "Legit, I've got some things to tell you about my man, J-dog," Jonah harangued the crowd.
>   <sub>-*The 39 Clues; Unstoppable: Flashpoint*, chapter 27</sub>

**Was Jonah based on any specific celebrity?**